# Getting iTunes HD Film Details (though scraping, iTunes API or by other means)

Tags: api, web-scraping, itunes, movie

Is there a way to get the HD movie information (price, etc.) on iTunes store? This becomes especially tricky if the movie is sold as both HD and non-HD.

For example: *The Prestige* (iTunes id = *209960866*)

If you look the description in iTunes, you can get all 4 pricing options (i.e., buy HD, buy normal, rent HD, rent normal). However, as far as I know, this information cannot be scraped (or retrieved) programmatically (let me know if I am wrong).

If you look at the web: http://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/the-prestige/id209960866

You only get the normal buy price (I have also looked at the source code to see whether scraping works, it does not).

If you use iTunes lookup API: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=209960866

Again, you only get the normal buy price.

How can I access the other prices?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Scrapy project to scrape iTunes metadata and came across the same problem.

Change the User-Agent of your scraper to the following.

iTunes/9.0.3 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; en-ca)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem. I just found this:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/enterprise-partner-feed-flat.html

"The Enterprise Partner Feed is a data feed of the complete set of metadata from iTunes and the App Store. It is available for affiliate partners to fully incorporate aspects of the iTunes and App Store catalogs into a web site or app. The EPF is available in two different formats - either as the files necessary to build a relational database or as stand-alone flat files that are country and media dependent."

and then down at the bottom of the page you can see in the TV section (hopefully that applies to movies as well) you can see listings for:

sd_price - The price to buy the TV episode in Standard Quality format.
hq_price - The price to buy the TV episode in High Quality format.
lc_rental_price - The price to rent the TV episode in Low Quality format.
sd_rental_price - The price to rent the TV episode in Standard Quality format.
hd_rental_price - The price to rent the TV episode in High Quality format.

Hope that helps. I haven't gotten to mess with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The description of hq_price says "The retail price of the high quality, DRM-free (iTunes Plus) video...".  I don't believe this is the HD price.

I see no way to access this information.  Have you found otherwise?